# MSSQL fixed getdate() per query

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc, getdate

If I need to update a few million rows with the current date, and I update them with the value getdate(), is this the query run time or the specific row runtime? Meaning will all rows have the same date or will some rows have values that are a few milliseconds off?

If it is the specific row time is there a way to insert the query start time instead?

Comment: If you do `update yourtable set yourcolumn = getdate()` all rows will end up with the same value regardless of how long it takes. It is a "runtime constant"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple statements in your batch you will get different values from `getdate()`.  If you have only a single update then you will get the same value.

If you have multiple statements you can declare a datetime variable and assign it the value of `getdate()`, then use that variable in your following statements.

```
DECLARE @static_date DATETIME = getdate();

UPDATE mytable SET MyDate = @static_date;
UPDATE mytable2 SET YourDate = @static_date;
...
```

Answer (score -2):

declare @startDate datetime;

set @startDate = getdate();

update [Orders] set [OrderDate] = @startdate

Comment: There is no need to assign to a variable for this case